# Conditional probability of sum of exponentials

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I want to evaluate, for $X_i$ i.i.d unit exponentially distributed random variables and for some $t \ge 0$:
$$
P(X_1+X_2>t ~,~X_1<t)
$$
and more generally, I want to work towards solving:
$$
P(X_1+X_2+...+X_k>t ~,~X_1+X_2+...+X_{k-1} <t)
$$
I'm stuck on evaluating the first expression, can I proceed as follows:
\begin{align*}
P(X_1+X_2>t ~,~X_1<t) & =P(X_1+X_2>t ~|~ X_1=y<t) P(X_1<t)\\
&=P(X_2>t-y)P(X_1<t)\\
&=e^{t-y}(1-e^{-t}) \quad y<t
\end{align*}
Can i do this as I condition on a value of y? Then generalising:
\begin{align*}
&P(X_1+..+X_k>t ~,~X_1+...+X_{k-1}<t) \\
=&P(X_1+..+X_k>t ~|~ X_1+..+X_{k-1}=y<t) P(X_1+..+X_{k-1}<t)\\
=&P(X_k>t-y)P(\Gamma(k-1,1)<t)
\end{align*}
where $\Gamma(a,b)$ is a gamma distributed random variable with parameters $a,b$. If the working is right, is there a better way of summarising this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $X = X_k$ and $Y = X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_{k-1}$ where the $X_i$ are
iid standard exponential random variables and so $Y \sim \Gamma(k-1,1)$,
\begin{align}
P\{X+Y > t, Y < t\} &= \int_{y=0}^t \frac{y^{k-2}}{(k-2)!}e^{-y} \int_{x=t-y}^\infty e^{-x}
\, \mathrm dx\, \mathrm dy\\
&= \int_{y=0}^t \frac{y^{k-2}}{(k-2)!}e^{-y} e^{-(t-y)}\, \mathrm dy\\
&= e^{-t}\int_{y=0}^t \frac{y^{k-2}}{(k-2)!}\, \mathrm dy\\
&= \frac{t^{k-1}}{(k-1)!}e^{-t}
\end{align}

Comment: Was there anything wrong with the expression you had before the edit? The general form?

Comment: so the inside integral becomes:
$$
\int_{x=0}^t e^{-x} \int_{y=t-x}^\infty  \frac{1}{(k-1)!} y^{k-1}e^{-y}dydx
$$
?

Comment: @dimebucker91 Actually, I had the right answer the first time around. See my yet-again revised answer.